# How to crop a part of image using pen path?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

I have made a work path using the *pen* tool. I wanted to crop the selected part out, but when create a vector mask, it leaves the inside part and crops out the outside part:
[image]

---

[image]

Comment: It works the same way you handle that stuff with shape layers. If you just applied the vector mask and the path is selected, you can just change it, but otherwise you have to probably use the [`Path selection tool` to select the path](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/editing-paths.html#change_the_overlap_mode_for_the_selected_path_component) and then in the tool options you got [`Path operations` icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D2fKC.png), which is like the two overlapping squares. You'll want to change that to `Subtract`.

Comment: Cropping means a square cut in print production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Pen tool options along the top, set it to *Combine Shapes*

[image]

Draw each corner piece like this to make your work path. Because you chose to combine the shapes, and although this looks like four paths, it will function as one combined path.

[image]

Then apply it as a vector mask

[image]

Just a quick note here about terminology, just in case you ever have to search for tutorials. This isn't called "cropping". Cropping is when you trim an image down to a different size square/rectangle using the Crop tool.  What you are trying to do is called "masking".